# Fragment issue (Multiple instances)

Tags: android, fragment, multiple-instances

I have this annoying problem which I don't know how to solve. The problem is very straightforward:

I have `FragmentA` which pushes `FragmentB` (a `ListView`) on a button click.
In `FragmentB` I can push `FragmentA` with a `OnItemClick`. So you see, the depth is infinite.

The problem is when I pushed `FragmentB` the second time, and then go back (2 times) to first instance of `FragmentB` I have the items from the first and second instance in the `ListView`. If I were about to make 10 instances, then I would have the items of all 10 instances in my first instance.

Can anyone explain the problem and please provide me a solution?

EDIT (code snippet):

```
FollowersFragment frag = new FollowersFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(Constants.USER_ID, userId);
frag.setArguments(bundle);
((MainActivity) getActivity()).pushFragment(frag);

public void pushFragment(TrigdFragment fragment) {
    pushFragment(fragment, new AnimationObject());
}

public void pushFragment(TrigdFragment fragment, AnimationObject animate) {
    switchContent(fragment, animate, false);
}

public void switchContent(TrigdFragment fragment, AnimationObject anim,
        boolean clearBackStack) {
    ActionBarHelper mActionBarHelper = ActionBarHelper.getInstance();
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    FragmentManager mgr = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (clearBackStack) {
        mActionBarHelper.setDisplayHomeAsDrawerEnabled(true);
        mgr.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    } else {
        mActionBarHelper.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    fragment.setupActionBar(getResources());

    FragmentTransaction ft = mgr.beginTransaction();

    boolean doingAnimation = false;
    if (Util.hasIcecreamSandwich()) {
        doingAnimation = anim != null;

        if (doingAnimation) {
            ft.setCustomAnimations(anim.enterResource, anim.exitResource,
                    anim.popEnterResource, anim.popExitResource);
        }
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "current");

    if (!clearBackStack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    }

    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    if (Util.hasIcecreamSandwich()) {
        if (doingAnimation) {
            // This can't be done immediately because the transaction may
            // not
            // yet be committed. Commits are are posted to the main
            // thread's message loop.
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how many fragments you have....???

Comment: I have these two, FragmentA and Fragment B. But they can start eachother (circular).

Comment: *So you see, the depth is infinite.* - if you use new instances each time. But you can switch between only two instance of those fragments and avoid the problem. *I have the items from the first and second instance in the ListView* - do you by any chance have `static` data in that fragment?

Comment: I'm pushing the frag with ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "current"); and then ft.addToBackStack(null);

Comment: FollowersFragment fragment = new FollowersFragment();

Comment: The only static I'm using is a singleton class to get the cached items before loading from remote.

Comment: Show your code please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue had nothing to do with multiple instances. It was a `Listener` which provided the problem, my mistake. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new instance of the Fragments you can use `replace` function of `FragmentTransaction`

`transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);`

- [Replacing one fragment with another in Android dynamically](http://www.sapandiwakar.in/technical/replacing-fragments/)
- http://notionink.wikidot.com/rajeshbabu
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: @Carnal still having issues..??

Comment: Yes I still have probe.

Comment: are you generatting fragments dynamically..??